# Adding 'end' foundation class to div in PHP loop isn't styling it correctly

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Originally I had a bunch of large-4 columns that looked like this

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <h2>Title Here</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns end">foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where it displays 3 columns then drops the fourth and fifth columns down below the first 3 and floats them left because of the 'end' class'.

I want to create the same thing using values provided via fields from my WordPress Admin panel. The field is a text box with text that is delimited by new line character. From this, in my code I create an array by exploding the field by new line character. An example looks like this

```
Text from field:
Foo
Bar
Bazz
Buzz

$pcv = get_post_custom_values('text_from_field');
$text_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $pcv[0]);
```

So now `$text_array` is equal to `[Foo, Bar, Bazz, Buzz]`

With me so far?

Next I want to iterate over that array for each item in that array, I want to create a large-4 div and pump the current array value into that div. I also want to check if the current array value is the last value in the array and if so, append the 'end' class to it. That code would look like this.

```
<div class="large-12 columns>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
      $pcv = get_post_custom_values('text_from_field');
      $text_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $pcv[0]);
      foreach ($text_array as $text) { ?>
        <div class="large-4 columns <?php if($text == end($text_array)){ echo "end";} ?>">
          <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Given that there are 5 values, it should create the same html tree I showed at the beginning of this thread, and for the most part it does. The HTML itself looks fine, including the 'end class' being added to the last large-4.

The only problem is that the 4th and 5th columns aren't being floated left. They are behaving as normal and stacking directly underneath the 3rd column. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing? Is there something missing from my PHP?

DOM using the loop[image]

Comment: `php` has nothing to do with that. It's all about styles.

Comment: this is not "Bootstrap" its "Foundation"

Comment: @u_mulder can you explain please. Are you saying that my PHP is fine? and thank youI edited the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not at all a PHP issue and is related to your use of Foundation. Foundation supports a 12 column row. What that means is that your can only add the numbers on columns to 12 this is not working because 4*5 = 20.

So what you need is to either reduce the column down to 2 (2*5=10) the `end` class on the last element will make this all line up.

The other option if you want to use 4 is to create another row once you hit 3 elements. Then on the last element if it does not fill a row apply an end class

What you will see in html is

```
<!--I assume this is in a row???-->
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <h2>Title Here</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-2 columns">foo</div>
        <div class="large-2 columns">foo</div>
        <div class="large-2 columns">foo</div>
        <div class="large-2 columns">foo</div>
        <div class="large-2 columns end">foo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<!--I assume this is in a row???-->
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <h2>Title Here</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">foo</div>
        <div class="large-4 columns end">foo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not include the PHP because what you have appears to be working and you will just need to tweak it...

Comment: I see what you're saying but I was able to make five large-4 divs work within the large-12 div just fine. It just pushes any divs over the 12 down below it. That's why I used the end class to line it all up. Here is a screenshot of my HTML rendered

[example](http://imgur.com/a/CpetN)

Comment: This may work "sometime" but your using the framework incorrectly and that is liable to cause these issues. If you want that look then you should be doing the second option in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'm seeing now that my problem lies in the length of whatever text I'm injecting, which as you mention stems from going beyond the 12 column length. Just because works doesn't mean I should do it I suppose :P

Comment: Glad I could help! If you need assistance with the PHP I can offer that up as well but it looks like you have a decent handle on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with .PHP rather how you are using design elements.

Personally what I would do is first design your layout so that it displays as you want it, then worry about feeding an array into it.

It looks like you are defining column class within the loop here:

```
 foreach ($text_array as $text) { ?>
         <div class="large-4 columns <?php if($text == end($text_array)) 
             {echo "end";} ?>">
          <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
```

I would recommend defining layout outside of the loop.  I would not consider myself an expert, but it has been my experience in the past that contolling structure/layout from within loops becomes increasingly difficult as you use the same loop for other intended purposes in general.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not defining column class within the loop, column class exists are part of the Foundation Library. Inside the loop I'm merely saying, if the current index is the last item in the array, append the 'end' class (also Foundation) to that div

Comment: Ok, I understand that then.  Like I said I am not an expert, but I can tell you I do not think your problem has anything to do with .php.  It has do do with your use of design elements.  The easiest thing to do would be build the design layout, then write a loop of defining variables from $text_array.  Call the variables into place as need be.  That way, future changes to the orriginal $text_array (i.e adding/removing from array) will not have any impact

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is correctly.

I think it's the missing quotes at the first div, that is bugging the row behavior.

```
<div class="large-12 columns>
```

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG3Oj.jpg)

**EDIT**:
@modusAndrew The answer that has been accepted is not correct. It is perfectly accepted to put more columns than 12. A completely valid example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 large-6">
      50% on desktop, 100%  on mobile
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 large-6">
      50% on desktop, 100%  on mobile
  </div>
</div>
```

See your code working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktW2X.jpg

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this was just a syntax error in my example and not my actual code :(

Comment: @modusAndrew The answer that has been accepted is not correct. It is perfectly accepted to put more columns than 12. A completely valid example:

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 large-6">
      50% on desktop, 100%  on mobile
   </div>
  <div class="small-12 large-6">
      50% on desktop, 100%  on mobile
   </div>
</div>

See your code working: http://imgur.com/a/dtpDl

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the answer accepted is correct. While yes your example (and originally mine) worked, it started to fail as soon as the text within the p tags of each column grew too long. Try it for yourself